# How I can receive data from Bosch Laser measure Bluetooth device Using flutter

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to get data from Bosch laser measure (GLM 50 c) using Bluetooth. I am using this plugin flutter_blue: ^0.8.0 to get data via Bluetooth. My mobile device successfully connected with this Bosch device I can read its services and characteristics which that plugin allow to read, from these characteristics I can get device name, manufacture name and model number which I am showing in attached image. But when Bosch device measure the distance I did not receive data from Bosch device to my mobile phone. Please help how I can achieve this.
Thank you.

[image]

This is my code.

```
RaisedButton(
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Text('READ', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
          onPressed: () async {
            print(
                "descriptors Length: ${characteristic.descriptors.length}");

            characteristic.read();

            var sub = characteristic.value.listen((value) {
              setState(() {
                Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.fromList(value);
                String string = String.fromCharCodes(bytes);
                readValues[characteristic.uuid] = string;
                // Uint8List uint8list = Uint8List.fromList(value);

                print("readVal: $value");
                print("cc value: $string");
              });
            });
            List<int> chrd = await characteristic.read();
            Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.fromList(chrd);
            String string = String.fromCharCodes(bytes);
            print("readVal: $chrd");
            print("cc chrd: $string");
            sub.cancel();
          },
        ),
```

Comment: The GLM 50 c seems to allow connections via BLE and Bluetooth Classic, so you are probably using the correct library. Do you connect to the device using the phones bluetooth dialog or from within your app? The bluetooth dialog only allow connections to Bluetooth Classic. What are you doing in your app to receive data? Please [edit] your question and add some code as text.

Comment: Since there is no official description of the Bluetooth protocol you have to figure it out yourself. A good starting point would be a generic BLE scanner such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile)

Comment: [This](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/hacking-the-bosch-glm-20-laser-measuring-tape/msg1331649/#msg1331649) post describes the serial protocol for Bluetooth Classic connections. You would need to use a different library like [flutter_bluetooth_serial](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bluetooth_serial)

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan first pair device with my phone after paring I connect the device from my Application. I use stream listener to get values and convert in to readable string I also edit my Question.